# How do I define an ad-hoc ordering in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table that I want to summarize, and whose summarized results I want to order in a certain way.

Let's say it's a table containing fruits and sales by week: I would like an output with total sales by fruit (up to here nothing strange), but the fruits should be ordered as follows:

- cranberries
- bananas
- strawberries
- all others in alphabetical order

Is it possible to do that using SQL only and without defining a table that sets the ordering for each fruit?

If using a specific SQL dialect or function, I am targeting SQLite

Comment: You can try to achive this behaviour with a CASE WHEN into the ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

Simply with a CASE statement...

```
ORDER BY CASE MyColum WHEN 'cranberries' THEN '001'
                      WHEN 'bananas' THEN '002'
                      WHEN 'strawberries' THEN '003'
                      ELSE MyColum 
         END
```

Comment: I'd imagine sorting by an `int` would be faster: `THEN 1` etc

Comment: Common sorting value is varchar (ProductName). Conversion to varchar is inevitable.

Comment: ORDER BY MyColum IN ('cranberries', 'bananas', 'strawberries') DESC